# How shall I understand this description of how pickling and unpickling work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am confused by the following description of pickling and unpickling from *Python in a Nutshell*. The uses of "otherwise" and "in this one case" are unclear to me, and I am not sure what case they refer to. I'd appreciate if you could   rephrase it in a clearer way, maybe in pseudo code?

> Here is how  pickle  saves the state of instance object  x  of class 
>   T  and later reloads the saved state into a new instance  y  of  T 
>   (the first step of the reloading is always to make a new empty
>   instance  y  of  T , except where we explicitly say otherwise in the
>   following):
>
> • When  `T`  supplies the method  `__getstate__` ,  pickle  saves the
>   result  d  of calling `T.__getstate__(x)` .
>
> • When `T` supplies the method  `__setstate__`,  `d`  can be of any
>   type, and  pickle reloads the saved state by calling 
>   `T.__setstate__(y,   d)` .
>
> • Otherwise,  `d`  must be a dictionary, and  pickle  just sets 
>   `y.__dict__ =   d`.
>
> • Otherwise, when  `T`  supplies the method  `__getnewargs__` , and 
>   pickle  is pickling with protocol 2 or higher,  pickle  saves the
>   result  `t`  of calling  `T.__getnewargs__(x)` ;  `t`  must be a
>   tuple.
>
> • pickle , in this one case, does not start with an empty  `y` , but
>   rather creates  `y`  by executing  `y   =   T.__new__(T, *t)` , which
>   concludes the reloading.
>
> • Otherwise, by default,  pickle  saves as  `d`  the dictionary
>   `x.__dict__` .
>
> • When  `T`  supplies the method  `__setstate__`,  pickle  reloads
>   the saved state by calling  `T.__setstate__ (y,   d)` .
>
> • Otherwise,  pickle  just sets  `y.__dict__ =   d` .

Comment: It's as if the explanation of unpickle needs to be unpickled to be understandable. I'm guessing "this one case" maybe is when the class has a `__getnewargs__` method?  And "otherwise" is when there's neither a `__setstate__` or `__getnewargs__` method?

Comment: Thanks. Which "otherwise"?

Comment: I think maybe point 3 and 4 could swap places, and the final point could be removed, since it seems to just repeat point 3. The "otherwise" in point 6 is the only one that deals with pickling, so that one is not so ambiguous.

Comment: But I'm mostly guessing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That description really needs indentation or something to better indicate what goes with what.  Here's what it's trying to say, as a flowchart:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. How did you draw the diagram?

Comment: I used an online drawing tool at www.draw.io.

Comment: Awesome, pickle documentation is so difficult to read. Where does `__reduce__` happen in this diagram?

Comment: Actually the diagram is wrong, if `__getnewargs__` and `__getstate__` are provided, they are both called at pickling